# <liferay-ui:search-container> scriplets

Tags: liferay, jstl, el, scriptlet

How can I get rid of scriplets here?

```
<liferay-ui:search-container>
    <liferay-ui:search-container-results
        results="<%= BookLocalServiceUtil.getBooks(searchContainer.getStart(), searchContainer.getEnd()) %>" 
        total="<%= BookLocalServiceUtil.getBooksCount() %>"
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution!

In .jsp

```
<liferay-ui:search-container> <liferay-ui:search-container-results results="${bookListArray}" />
```

In `render` method:

```
    String pageName = request.getParameter("pageName");
    List<Book> bookList = null;
    try {
        bookList = BookLocalServiceUtil.getBooks(QueryUtil.ALL_POS, QueryUtil.ALL_POS);
    } catch (SystemException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    request.setAttribute("bookListArray", bookList);
```

Comment: Just an advise: be careful with those QueryUtil.ALL_POS. If you have just a few records it doesn't matter, but for great ammounts of data it will be a very bad idea. Send a start and end in your request, and pass them to your service call to retrieve just a set of records.

Comment: Thank you, @JuanManuelRogado !